# Jquery video recording plugin need to save video via PHP

Tags: jquery, video, recording

Anybody know about any video recording jquery plugin for all the browser?

I have tried few plugin which are listed below.

https://www.scriptcam.com/demo_2.cfm
https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I work for Ziggeo.

WebRTC currently only works on Chrome, Opera and Firefox. You need to fall back to Flash on Safari, Internet Explorer. On mobile, you can use WebRTC on some Android devices and have to fall back to input capture on all other mobile browsers.

I don't know any jQuery plugin that can do it for you at this point. There are a some commercial solutions out there (including Ziggeo) that handle both the front-end as well as the back-end for you.